# How to check if you have written ES6 code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have written a bunch of Javascript code. I was never aware of the fact that there are multiple JS 'versions', like ES5 and ES6.

I now have this project hosted on Github, and somebody pointed out that because i'm using ES6 code, I might need to convert it to ES5 with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

However, I have no idea which parts of my code use ES6. I could read all of the ES6 specifications, but is there some kind of tool/checker which marks all of the ES6 code in my project?

Comment: `eslint` for example.

Comment: Well if it works as is in your current environment, no you don't need Babel. If you used some feature that's not supported, you would know.

Comment: @Bergi I host this project on Github, so others with possibly different browsers/runtimes run it as well

Comment: @ThomasW Well then *they* should be able to transpile it for their needs. Or do you host production files (transpiled and minified) and guarantee support for certain environments?

Comment: @Bergi dude your missing the entire point, if someone is making a project with the hopes that it be publicly available, its expected that it should just work on others computers. Even though this is a github project and not a website, but the same ideas or a website would appy, you wouldnt want to average user having to compile the entire webpage with babel before just going on to it to have it work

Comment: @bluejayke "*its expected that it should just work on others computers*" - nobody expects the code works in IE5. Where's the boundary? And no, not the end users should use babel, but the website authors.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://jshint.com/ or http://www.jslint.com/ - will detect ES6 specific specifications by just adding your code in the console

Comment: You're such a legend!

Answer (score 10):

Add it into the Babel repl and see if it changes:

https://babeljs.io/repl/

:-) Hope that helps

Other than that it might be best to setup es6 with babel using webpack, gulp, rollup etc

So that if you write es6 or es5 it will automatically get converted and you can learn some new features on the way while still supporting es5 only browsers